# How secure is Android ICS keystore?

Tags: android, android-keystore

I want to use ICS keystore to store private keys and certificates. However I am concerned about its security. It seems any application can read and get private keys and certificates installed in keystore (without privateKeys password). The only security I noticed is the permission dialog displayed to user.

**Is it so (Correct me if I am wrong)?**

**Any other procedure to store private and public keys securely?**

Comment: why don't you store certificates in sqlCipher?